# Line breaks VS Page Breaks

Tags: line-breaks, page-break

I am new to Visual Studio Code, but I understand writing code.  I used to use Dreamweaver and it would break code up by page breaks (if the code went beyond your visible screen it would show you the rest of the code WITHOUT writing a new number).  In Visual Studio Code I have to scroll very far to the right to see the end of the line.

Perhaps it is poorly written code, but how do I see an line of code without having to scroll?

Thanks!

I cannot figure it out.... help

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code, you can use the "Word Wrap" feature to automatically wrap lines of code that are too long to fit on the screen.

view/word wrap or alt+Z is a default key